# Error inflating class fragment error in google maps API

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

Getting the below error while trying to insert a map fragment into my project.  I can't for the life of me figure our what is going on...  I have racked my brain trying to get this simple thing to work by following the instructions in the basic tutorial word for word and I am still stuck.

```
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.main.pkg/com.main.pkg.NewHomepage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at com.main.pkg.NewHomepage.onCreate(NewHomepage.java:34)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     ... 11 more
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     ... 22 more
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.main.pkg-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.main.pkg-1, /system/lib]]
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
03-24 15:28:38.740: E/AndroidRuntime(3683):     ... 25 more'
```

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/number_mail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mail_button"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:textColor="#f900"
    />

    <Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_image"
    android:layout_width="26dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/mail_button"
    />
            <LinearLayout 

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            >
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

            <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            />




            </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried using 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment' instead but I get the same error.

What could I possibly be missing here?  My manifest seems to have all the correct info.

Comment: it seems like your `google_play_services_lib` not found.

Comment: I am pretty sure it can be found, I copied it over to my workspace and  imported it into eclipse.  When I right click my project and go to properties, I see it referenced in the library as you can see here in this screenshot:

http://s15.postimg.org/w8i0aovij/Untitled.png

Comment: let me see your manifest.xml file and your code

Comment: I just tried this with the simple tutorial and I got the same error.  I posted another question with that code to simplify things.  Can you answer it here?:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625303/log-cat-error-on-google-maps-api-using-basic-tutorial