# LOG CAT Error on Google Maps API using basic tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-maps

I submitted an similar question earlier on a more advanced project, so I thought I would simplify things by using the maps API tutorial provided by google to try and replicate the error I was getting, and I get the same error!  Good and bad, at least I know it's not my project causing the error.

Now I just need to figure out why I am getting this error!  I am new to programming but I followed this tutorial here verbatum:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Here is the error I am getting:

```
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     ... 11 more
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.ex(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4745)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     ... 20 more
```

Here is my simple MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

here is my simple activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"/>
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="HIDDEN"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The only thing I can think of is that my manifest file is improperly set up.  But I followed the instructions and Eclipse didn't give me an error on it.  I am up in arms here trying to figure this out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you understand by reading this Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  `You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Answer (score 1):

Your logcat clearly said

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-24 20:47:03.244: E/AndroidRuntime(6250):     at    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
```

**Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest**

> Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the
>   following declaration within the element. This embeds the version of
>   Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

You need to add `<meta-data>` under `<application>` tag into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

This is because latest google play services requires a version name, which is to be mentioned using `<meta-data .. />` inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
....<application>
 ..............
 <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="Key" />

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Also Extends your `Activity` to `FragmentActivity`

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the below as a child of application tag as mentioned in the other answer.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also you have

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

So change this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

Since you use `SupportMapFragment` you need to use `FragmentActivity` which is the base class for support based fragments.

Also change this

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"/> // remove this
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put both meta tag with your API key....in between applicationTag.
Also add permission tag with your package name which you use in Google console in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
  <permission
        android:name="com.xyz.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="com.xyz.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

 <application
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >   
    ..... 
    .....

        <meta-data
                        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                        android:value="Put Your API Key here"/> 

                    <meta-data
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        </application>
```

Extend your class activity to fragment activity use below

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Insted of this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing following lines in your Manifest file,

```
 <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Please write these lines before your MAP-API Key tag, inside the  tag.

Once you will complete these changes you will get Fragment error as you are using latest version of Map but you are using Activity inside your code, So you need to change following as well,

Extends your `Activity` to `FragmentActivity`

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```